# Store the tokens after splitting

Tags: perl, split, token

I have the the following Perl statement which split a string by delimiters |,\ or /

```
@example = split(/[\|\\\/]/,$i);
```

How to store the tokens after splitting?

For example input:

> John|Mary/Matthew

What I get is:

> (John, Mary, Matthew)

What I want:

> (John, |, Mary, /, Matthew)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put a capturing group inside your regex to save the delimiter:

```
my $str = 'John|Mary/Matthew';

my @example = split /([\|\\\/])/, $str;

use Data::Dump;
dd @example;
```

Outputs:

```
("John", "|", "Mary", "/", "Matthew")
```

This is documented in the last paragraph of: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: This is called "separator retention mode"